# Show absolute value in binomial graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

Recombining binomial price lattice

[image: binomial price lattice]

Hi, I want to show absolute values (numbers) in each node of this graph. I have tried to plot values for each node but there were errors occurred. 
Can any one help me to tackle this problem. I appreciate any help. I look forward your kind help.

```
from math import *
import pylab as z;
import numpy as np;

def PriceMovements(S0, down, up, totalsteps, upsteps):
    S = S0*(pow(up, upsteps))*(pow(down, totalsteps-upsteps))
    return S

def binomial(d, u, p):
    g = np.random.binomial(1,p)

    if g == 1:
        return u
    else:
        return d

#Use the following numbers to console the setting for binomial graph

nodes = 8 #Nodes
S = 1080.0 #Initial spot price
u = 1.1346 #Up factor
d = 0.8814 #Down factor
p = 0.7844 # Probability
r = 1.08 #1+Interest rate
n = 3 #Steps

numberofpaths = 2**nodes
valuelist = [] #Emptylist
z.figure(0) #Generating the figure
temp = S #Temporary variable

for i in range(0, numberofpaths, 1):
    valuelist =[]
    S = temp;
    for c in range(0, nodes + 1, 1):
        valuelist.append(S)
        S = S*binomial(d, u, p)
    z.plot(range(0, nodes + 1, 1), valuelist)

z.title("Price movements")
z.xlabel("Nodes")
z.ylabel("S(n)")
z.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `text`  :

```
# after z.plot(range(0, nodes + 1, 1), valuelist)
for i in range(nodes):
    z.text(i+.2,valuelist[i]-25,'{:4.1f}'.format(valuelist[i]))
```

for

[image]

just tune the offsets for best apparence.